# Different results PyTorch vs Libtorch

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pytorch, libtorch

I am trying to calculate a disparity image for the same traced model in python and c++ but I am getting different outputs.
I tried and follow the same steps in c++ as in python but it seems I missed something.
I am using the mono_640x192 pretrained model.
Here is the code in python that I tried to reproduce

```
input_image = pil.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
original_width, original_height = input_image.size
        
input_image = input_image.resize((feed_width, feed_height), pil.LANCZOS)
input_image = transforms.ToTensor()(input_image).unsqueeze(0)

input_image = input_image.to(device)
features = encoder(input_image)
outputs = depth_decoder(features)
for key, value in outputs.items():
    print(key, value)
    disp = outputs[("disp", 0)]
    disp_resized = torch.nn.functional.interpolate([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f7bb.jpg)disp, (original_height, original_width), mode="bilinear", align_corners=False)
    output_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))[0]
    scaled_disp, depth = disp_to_depth(disp, 0.1, 100)
     
    name_dest_npy = os.path.join(output_directory, "{}_disp.npy".format(output_name))
    np.save(name_dest_npy, scaled_disp.cpu().numpy())
    disp_resized_np = disp_resized.squeeze().cpu().numpy()

    vmax = np.percentile(disp_resized_np, 95)
    normalizer = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=disp_resized_np.min(), vmax=vmax)
    mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalizer, cmap='magma')
        
    colormapped_im = (mapper.to_rgba(disp_resized_np)[:, :, :3] * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    im = pil.fromarray(colormapped_im)

    name_dest_im = os.path.join(output_directory, "{}_disp.jpeg".format(output_name))
    im.save(name_dest_im)
```

and here what my c++ code

```
cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(640, 192));
cv::imwrite("/home/monodepth2/cpp/assets/test_image1.jpg", image);
torch::Tensor input_tensor = torch::from_blob(image.data, {1, image.rows, image.cols, 3}, torch::kByte);
input_tensor = input_tensor.to(torch::kFloat32).div_(255);
input_tensor = input_tensor.permute({0, 3, 1, 2});
input_tensor = input_tensor.sub_(0.5).div_(0.5);
input_tensor = input_tensor.to(torch::kCUDA);
at::Dict<at::IValue, at::IValue> output_dict = outputs.forward({input_tensor}).toGenericDict();

torch::Tensor disp = output_dict.at("disp0").toTensor();
at::Tensor disp_resized = torch::nn::functional::interpolate(
    disp,
    torch::nn::functional::InterpolateFuncOptions()
        .size(std::vector<int64_t>({original_height, original_width}))
        .mode(torch::kBilinear)
        .align_corners(false)
);
auto result = disp_to_depth(disp, 0.1, 100);
torch::Tensor scaled_disp = result.first;
torch::Tensor depth = result.second;
std::string output_name = std::filesystem::path(image_path).stem();

std::string name_dest_im = output_directory + "/" + output_name + "_disp.jpeg";

torch::Tensor disp_resized_squeezed = disp_resized.squeeze();
torch::Tensor disp_resized_cpu = disp_resized_squeezed.cpu();
float* disp_resized_data = disp_resized_cpu.data_ptr<float>();
std::size_t numel = disp_resized_cpu.numel();
std::vector<float> sorted_data(disp_resized_data, disp_resized_data + numel);
std::sort(sorted_data.begin(), sorted_data.end());

float vmax = sorted_data[static_cast<std::size_t>(numel * 0.95)];
float vmin = *std::min_element(disp_resized_data, disp_resized_data + numel);

cv::Mat disp_resized_image_rgb = cv::Mat(original_height, original_width, CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < original_height; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < original_width; ++j) {
        // Map the tensor values to the 0-255 range for grayscale
        uint8_t pixel_value = static_cast<uint8_t>((disp_resized_data[i * original_width + j] - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) * 255);
        disp_resized_image_rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(pixel_value, pixel_value, pixel_value);
    }
}
cv::Mat colormapped_im;
cv::applyColorMap(disp_resized_image_rgb, colormapped_im, cv::COLORMAP_MAGMA);
return 0;
```

What is wrong with my approach? Let me know if more information is needed.

The image on the left is the output of the c++ algorithm and on the right is from python
[image]